# Expressing "Is that the case?"

Tags: word-choice

If I put,

> 迷惑なことはありませんか？

How does it differ from:

> 迷惑なことはありますか？

Is it like the same thing said a bit different?

Comment: Please provide context such as where you got this sentence, what you want to say, in what context, etc

Comment: I'm trying to say is there anything troubling you kind of.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between

> 迷惑なことはありませんか？

and

> 迷惑なことはありますか？

is the same as, in English, the difference between

> Isn't there something troubling you?

and

> Is there anything troubling you?

In the former sentence, the speaker is assuming that there *is* something troubling the listener. The speaker would be surprised if there isn't something troubling the listener.

For another English example, consider the following conversation:

> A: "You know that guy John? He can be really annoying, sometimes."
>
> B: "Wait, isn't John your good friend?" *(Here, the speaker's assumption is that John is Speaker A's good friend. This is why the negative "isn't" is used instead of "is".)*
>
> A: "Yeah, but he's still really annoying."

It's the same principle, here as in Japanese: when we're assuming that something is the case, we use the negative form in the question.

In sum, you should probably go with

> 迷惑なことはありますか？

Otherwise, it would sound a bit presumptuous, almost as if it were common knowledge. If I were the listener, and you went with the other option, I would think: "Why are you assuming that there's something bothering me?"

---

As an aside, after questions marked with "か", proper form is to use a period "。" rather than a question mark "？". This is because you can already tell that you're dealing with a question from the particle "か".